# NextAuth signIn when user registers

Tags: reactjs, prisma, next.js13, next-auth, autologin

I dont know how to signIn the user when they register.

Im tryin to singIn the user when they register with credentials in next-auth. Currently im creating a user by adding it to the prisma db and if that succeeds, they get redirected to the signIn page, where they can signIn with their new credentials. Is there a way to automatically sign the user in when they register?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.